# Geometric meaning of $\nabla_{[i}(x^i \nabla_{j]}x^j)$ and $(\nabla_{[i}x^i )\nabla_{j]}x^j$

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning, tensors, curvature

While teaching myself tensor calculus I have come up with [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71613/12306)
proof of the 2-D hairy ball theorem.
When trying to generalize this proof to higher dimensions I get the term
$$\nabla_{[i}(x^i \nabla_{j]}x^j) = (\nabla_{[i}x^i )\nabla_{j]}x^j - 1/2R_{ij} x^i x^j $$

In 2 dimensions $(\nabla_{[i}x^i )\nabla_{j]}x^j$ is, up to a constant, the determinant of the  $\nabla_{i}x^j$ matrix. When it is zero this means that the direction $y^i\nabla_{i}x^j$ is independent of $y^i$. Therefore 
$ \nabla_{[i}x^i \nabla_{j]}x^j = 0 $ for constant norm vector fields on 2-d manifolds, since their covariant derivatives have to be perpendicular to the original field.

- What do these terms mean in higher dimensions?
- When are they everywhere zero or everywhere positive (or negative)?
- Does the dimension, being odd or even, play any role?
- What do their integrals mean?

I am particularly interested in these questions for the case when $x^i$ has constant norm.
Also is either of these a fairly common or well known tensor? Does either of them have a name?
I am working with a positive definite metric and $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: This may be more of a pure mathematics question, that could have a better home at [math.se]

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are apparently supposed to be vector fields.

Comment: @Qmechanic, yes

Comment: The determinant is just a coincidence. In general, if $A$ is a matrix with components $\nabla_i x^j$, then what you have is $(\operatorname{Tr}A)^2-\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)$. Apart from a factor of $2$, this is the sum of all products of 2 elements on the diagonal of $A$, minus the sum of all products of pairs of elements that are in reflected positions across the diagonal ($A_{12}A_{21} + A_{13}A_{31} + \cdots$). I'm not sure this is particularly useful though, or that it has a physical interpretation.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Funnily, that's the expression (modulo constants) for the second Chern class, if $A$ were the curvature form.

Comment: @user1997744 Could you expand on that